# Sql Server CASE count / dont count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select the counts of orders that have gone through our database.

from the orders, there are 3 parts i want to retrieve

1. total Order Count
2. Order Count of saleable orders
3. Order Count of orders that contain just *free* samples

If an order only contains free samples, the gross value for that order will naturally be `0`, if it is a normal order, the gross will naturally be `>0`

The gross field is in decimal format.

this is what i am trying to do at the moment.

```
COUNT(gross) as 'TotalOrders',
COUNT(case when gross = 0.00 THEN null else gross end) as 'OrderCount', 
COUNT(case when gross > 0.00 THEN gross else null end) as 'Samples',
```

how can i make the `COUNT()` function only increase by 1 if the order has a positive `gross` value?

I am doing this in `SQLServer`

My result is showing that `TotalOrders` is `1` *but* `OrderCount` and `Samples` are displaying as `0`

thanks.

Comment: Sum instead of count:  `SUM(case when gross > 0.00 THEN 1 else 0 end) as 'OrderCount',`

Comment: If `TotalOrders` has a value of 1, and `OrderCount` and `Samples` has a value of `0`, that suggests that that 1 row has a value of `< 0.00`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
sum(case when gross >= 0.00 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalOrders,
sum(case when gross = 0.00 then 1 else 0 end) as OrderCount, 
sum(case when gross > 0.00 then 1 else 0 end) as Samples
```

You may want `> 0.00`, but then `TotalOrders` would be the same as `Samples`.

Comment: Cheers this is exactly what i wanted. I didnt think to use SUM as i am also using that to get the total gross for that time period. you have used it in a clever way to actually temporarily change the value depending on that case.

Answer (score 0):

cast(COUNT(CASE when gross > 0.00 = THEN 1 else NULL END) as int) as Samples

Answer (score 0):

your suggested formula should work

```
with test as (select 1 as gross union all select  -1 as gross union all select  2)
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN gross > 0.00 THEN gross ELSE null END) as 'Samples' from test
```

Comment: cheers for the answer but this seems like a really complicated way of doing it. Quite new to SQL, what advantages does this bear over the answer below (accepted answer), it seems like using select a few times would have a negative performance?

Comment: my 'with Test ...' is sample data, to show you that your COUNT method does retrieve the expected value of 2